# How to access cleaned data in a Django form's clean() method?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'd like to implement an input field in a Django form, `phone_type`, which is only required when another field, `phone_number`, is filled in. I'm reading the example at https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/creating-conditionally-required-fields-in-django-forms/577/ on how to do this:

```
def clean(self):
    shipping = self.cleaned_data.get('shipping')

    if shipping:
        msg = forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        self.add_error('shipping_destination', msg)
    else:
        # Keep the database consistent. The user may have
        # submitted a shipping_destination even if shipping
        # was not selected
        self.cleaned_data['shipping_destination'] = ''

    return self.cleaned_data
```

where the models are defined as

```
from django.db import models

class ShippingInfo(models.Model):
    SHIPPING_DESTINATION_CHOICES = (
        ('residential', "Residential"),
        ('commercial', "Commercial"),
    )

    shipping = models.BooleanField()
    shipping_destination = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=SHIPPING_DESTINATION_CHOICES,
        blank=True
    )
```

When comparing this code to the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other, however, I notice that there is no call to `super().clean()`. Instead of accessing `self.cleaned_data` directly, should I do

```
cleaned_data = super().clean()
shipping = cleaned_data.get('shipping')
```

in the first lines of the custom `clean()` method?

(I would also be interested in ways to make the field conditionally visible without requiring additional jQuery/JavaScript code, e.g. using Django Crispy Forms and/or the [`HiddenInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput) widget).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forminstance.is_valid` or `forminstance.full_clean` will call your form's clean method implicitly by which time `forminstance.cleaned_data` will have the dict populated with the data in the right type according to the form fields. The call to `super` in the example you posted is in case you have inheritance in your form class hierarchy.
For clarification. It won't hurt if you have `super` but it won't change anything if you're not inheriting from a form class that doesn't have any fields defined.